# When can you use an adjective to imply a noun?

Tags: grammaire

I saw this sentence:

> Mais le plus intéressant avec le bitcoin, c’est la technologie qu’il y a derrière.

A literal translation of course is "But the most interesting about bitcoin..." rather than "But the most interesting *thing* about bitcoin", even if that's how we would say it in English.

I would have phrased this as *mais la chose la plus intéressante...* and not have realized it isn't idiomatic. When can you omit the noun this way, and is it obligatory or optional? Is it more idiomatic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Mais **la chose la plus intéressante** avec le bitcoin [...]* would have been idiomatic, just a little longer but still common.

*Mais **le plus intéressant** avec le bitcoin [...]* is of course also idiomatic but it is not a case where the noun *chose* has been omitted as the sentence would have been *mais **la** plus intéressant**e** avec le bitcoin, [...]* which just doesn't work unless *chose* has explicitely been mentioned earlier.

Here, *intéressant* is used as a neutral noun, as the TLFi tells:

> [Intéressant](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/int%C3%A9ressant)
> [...]
> **III.** − *Emploi substantivé masculin singulier à valeur de neutre.* Ce qui est intéressant (dans quelque chose, quelqu'un), ce qui fait l'intérêt de (quelque chose, quelqu'un). *Revenez! Vous manquez le plus intéressant. C'est à Ruth de nous parler de son mari...* (Giraudoux, *Sodome*, 1943, I, 1, p. 33). *En autrui, elle [notre attention] ne poursuit pas l'existence, mais l'« intéressant », c'est-à-dire le pittoresque* (Mounier, *Traité caract.*, 1946, p. 484)

Comment: I didn't even notice the gender change. The subtleties still escape me after all these years. Thanks.

Comment: In English, we generally only use neutral nouns for people (and only in the plural) — *the dead, the poor, the meek, the merciful, the dispossessed, the educated.* This may be what was confusing for the OP, as in the example it's used for a singular thing.